# How to tell when a UITableViewCell has been dequeued?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell`, and within that cell, I set up a timer to update a label in the cell with the current time. So every second this timer triggering, and updating this label.
But when a user, scrolls passed this cell, or otherwise the cell is not onscreen, I feel like I should halt the timer; no use updating a label that isn't currently being displayed right?

Is there any sort of way to check that a cell is on screen? Or hasn't been dequeued?

Here's some code since ya'll love it:

```
class TeamBattleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {    
    @IBOutlet weak var resultsSubtitleLabel: MantisLabel!
    var timer = Timer()
    func updateDisplay() {
        ...
        updateTime()
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func updateTime() {
        /*
        if self.is_dequeud {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        */
        let man = TeamBattleManager.get()
        let d = man.end_date.offsetFrom(date: Date())
        resultsSubtitleLabel.text = d+" remaining"
    }   
}
```

Comment: `didEndDisplaying` is not enough in your case?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614870-tableview

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. It doesn't trigger when pushing modals onto the stack or swapping to a different tab with via UITabViewController, but I didn't really expect it to.

Comment: Timers in cells isn't a great approach. You should have a single timer in your view controller and when it fires, iterate over the visible cells and refresh them. You probably also want to run your timer faster than 1 second. `Timer` isn't very accurate since it is a deadline timer, not truly schedule and it is quite jittery.  You UI updates will be smoother if you run the timer at, say, 0.2s.  Also, your cell shouldn't have knowledge of the model. It is just a view. So `TeamBattleManager.get()` violates the separation of concerns principle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stop timer in `prepareForReuse()`

```
  override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    timer.invalidate()
  }
```

About second case (when some modal screen is displayed) - you should handle it in your view controller